# Loop doesn't behave the way I expect

Tags: java, while-loop, off-by-one

The code I have written compiles but does not produce the output I was expecting. It ends before I have put in all of my input data and doesn't give me the correct output. Any idea where the mistake(s) is?

Here's main program:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String coinFlip;
    int tossNumber, numberOfHeads, numberOfTails;
    float percHeads, percTails;
    tossNumber = 1;
    numberOfHeads = 0;
    numberOfTails = 0;

    while(tossNumber <= 8)
    {
        System.out.println("Please toss your coin and enter the side    showing.");
        System.out.println("h = heads, t = tails");
        coinFlip = keyboard.next();

        if(coinFlip.equals("h") || coinFlip.equals("t"))
        {
            if(coinFlip.equals("h"))
            {
                System.out.println("Thank you! Please toss your coin again.");
                tossNumber = tossNumber + 1;
                numberOfHeads = numberOfHeads + 1;
            }
            else

                System.out.println("Thank you! Please toss your coin again");
                tossNumber = tossNumber + 1;
                numberOfTails = numberOfTails + 1;

        }
        else
            System.out.println("Please enter a \"h\" or \"t\".");
    }
```

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! Don't forget to tell people what language you are using as well as what you expect the program to do, otherwise its pretty hard too assist you. I've guessed you are using C#.

Comment: `System.out.println` would suggest Java as there are Console.Writeline and Response.Write methods in C# that could be used.

Answer (score 3):

All i did is to added `{}` to your `else` and i got it perfectly 8 times, hope thats expected.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MC_GAMAD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String coinFlip;
        int tossNumber, numberOfHeads, numberOfTails;
        float percHeads, percTails;
        tossNumber = 1;
        numberOfHeads = 0;
        numberOfTails = 0;

        while (tossNumber <= 8) {
            System.out
                    .println("Please toss your coin and enter the side    showing.");
            System.out.println("h = heads, t = tails");
            coinFlip = keyboard.next();

            if (coinFlip.equals("h") || coinFlip.equals("t")) {
                if (coinFlip.equals("h")) {
                    System.out
                            .println("Thank you! Please toss your coin again.");
                    tossNumber = tossNumber + 1;
                    numberOfHeads = numberOfHeads + 1;
                } else {
                    System.out
                            .println("Thank you! Please toss your coin again");
                    tossNumber = tossNumber + 1;
                    numberOfTails = numberOfTails + 1;
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter a \"h\" or \"t\".");
            }

        }

    }
}
```